# how to get the current node reference from the range object

Tags: javascript, range, selection, contenteditable

I am trying to implement backspace functionality with out using html() method as it resets the range object of an element which is not allowed in my case.

Unfortunately, it is not working as expected when I have more than one node. Is there any way that I could get the current node reference from the range object?

Here is the code I tried.

```
    <div id="myDiv" style="color:red" contenteditable="true">The color of this text is red.<br>yellow</div>
        <br /><br />
        <button  id='two'>Backspace</button>

//javascript

$('#two').click(function() 
{
  var div = document.getElementById ("myDiv");
  var doc = div.ownerDocument || div.document;
  var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
  var sel = win.getSelection();
  var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  if (document.createRange) 
  {     // all browsers, except IE before version 9
    var textNode = div.firstChild;      // the text node inside the div
    if (textNode.data.length > 1) 
     {
      var rangeObj = document.createRange ();
      if(range.startOffset> 0)
      {
        // aligns the range to the second character
        rangeObj.setStart (textNode, range.startOffset-1);
        rangeObj.setEnd (textNode, range.startOffset);
      }

      rangeObj.deleteContents ();
     }
   }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 rangeObj.setStart (textNode, range.startOffset-1);
        rangeObj.setEnd (textNode, range.startOffset);
```

adding the following instead of above lines fixed my issue.

```
 rangeObj.setStart (range.startContainer, range.startOffset-1);
  rangeObj.setEnd (range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
```